# Probability of an n-sphere cap w.r.t. to the Angular Central Gaussian Distribution

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X \sim N[0,D]$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries, top-left to bottom-right, $d_1 \ge d_2 \ge d_3 \ge\dots\ge d_n > 0$.

Let $e_1$ be the unit vector in $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. $[1,0,...,0]^{\mathrm T}$. It is an eigenvector of $D$ associated with eigenvalue $d_1$.

Let $q$ be an element of $S^{n-1}$, i.e. $q\in\mathbb R^n$ and $\lVert q\rVert = 1$ where $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is the 2-norm.

Let $0 < b < \sqrt(2)$.

Question: Is it true that $$\mathrm{Pr}(\lVert X/\lVert X\rVert - q\rVert < b) \le \mathrm{Pr}(\lVert X/\lVert X\rVert - e_1\rVert < b)?$$

In words, does the angular central Gaussian distributed random vector $X/\lVert X\rVert$ have greater probability mass on the $n$-sphere cap (defined by $b$) centered at $e_1$ than any other point $q$ on the $n$-sphere?